# Disable dropdown option after selecting (even for new visitors)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm working on a website where people can sign up for an event. We've got 8 different teams, based on superhero's. Every team should choose 1 of the 8 superheroes, but non of them should choose the same one.

Is it possible to write some code to disable an option (for every new visitor of the website) after someone has chosen that superhero?

So if 2 people has chosen a superhero, there will only be 6 choices left. These six will be visible, but non-clickable.

So my html form code is (some titles/names are Dutch;)):

```
<form action="inschrijfformulier.php" method="post" id="cc-m-form-6876142651" target="_blank" class="cc-m-form cc-m-form-layout-1" onsubmit="javascript: setTimeout(function(){location.reload();}, 1000);return true;">
                                                <div class="cc-m-form-loading"></div>

                                                <div class="cc-m-form-view-sortable">
                                                    <div class="cc-m-form-view-element cc-m-form-select" data-action="element" required>
                                                        <label for="ma6b8be54cf86a6410">
    <div>Kies welke held jouw team is!</div>
    </label>
                                                        <div class="cc-m-form-view-input-wrapper">
                                                            <select name="teamnaam" class="cc-m-form-element-input" required>
                                                                <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Selecteer</option>
<option value="Superman">Superman</option>
<option value="Batman">Batman</option>
<option value="X-Men">X-Men</option>
<option value="MegaMindy">Mega Mindy</option>
<option value="Spiderman">Spiderman</option>
<option value="TheHulk">The Hulk</option>
<option value="HitGirl">Hit Girl</option>
<option value="Meerminman">Meerminman</option></select></div></div>
<input type="submit" value="Naar betalen" data-action="formButton">
```

So if you make a selection and submit the form, it wil link to inschrijfformulie.php, this .php file contains:

```
<?php 
$name = $_POST['teamnaam'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$rekeninghouder = $_POST['rekeninghouder'];
$aantalspelers = $_POST['aantalspelers'];
$spelernamen = $_POST['spelernamen'];
$formcontent="Teamnaam: $name \nEmail: $email \nRekeninghouder: $rekeninghouder \nAantal spelers: $aantalspelers \nSpelers: $spelernamen";
$recipient = "info@sidekickevents.nl";
$subject = "Inschrijfformulier";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
header("Location: https://www.ticketkantoor.nl/shop/bubbelvoetbal");
 exit;
?>
```

This makes sure that I'm getting an email with the information they fill in. This works great, I also can see which superhero they've chosen.
Hopefully someone can explain it, because I'm new to PHP!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You would need to save the choice of each team at the server, and update the UI of the other teams accordingly - possibly through sockets or long polling.

Comment: To answer your question, yes it possible, but you would have to store the selected value in a database or something else and use that to say what options are disabled or not.

Comment: So your website is accesible through other network? Or just in your localhost?

Comment: Whenever someone selects an option and submits the form, you must store the selected value in the database. Then on rendering the form, you must fetch all selected options from the database and disable them on the dropdown

Comment: You may also face problems when 2 people are selecting superheroes simultaneously. What if both of them select the same superhero at the same time?

Comment: After selecting each hero you need to save it on the server. You can also use socket.

Comment: Thanks everyone for those fast reactions.
I dont know anything about 'sockets', badly.
It accesible trough other network. 
How can i save the selected value in a database? i'm busy with googleing it;)

Comment: I would reccomend you to use ajax

Answer (score 1):

First, whenever an option is selected, save it in server. While drawing the list box value, consider the already selected (From Storage) and disable the option.

Check,

```
<option value="Mega Mindy" disabled>Mega Mindy</option>
```

```html
<div>
<select>
<option value="Superman">Superman</option>
<option value="Batman">Batman</option>
<option value="X-Men">X-Men</option>
<option value="Mega Mindy" disabled>Mega Mindy</option>
<option value="Spiderman">Spiderman</option>
<option value="The Hulk">The Hulk</option>
<option value="Hit Girl">Hit Girl</option>
<option value="Meerminman">Meerminman</option></select></div>
```

Comment: I´m sorry, but how do i save it in server? i'm new to php.

Comment: @OlafLangens Just add `PHP' tag in your question. Also add your code, phpians will help you out

Comment: @OlafLangens Is your code working fine? Do u want me to assist anything?

Comment: no still not working. What i've posted at the top is my code right now. So there's still nothing how I can save the option somewhere to the server. So now everyone can choose X-Men. But I want only person to choose X-Men..

Answer (score 0):

There is only one way to do it and it is related with server side. First you pick the user's choice:

Let's assume that your selectbox id is "heroes-combo" and you are using jQuery.

```
// this gives you the selected option's value.
$("#heroes-combo option:selected").attr("value");
```

Now send it to server side via ajax.

When a user enters the website you need to query your database which heroes are already selected. Lets say the database returns Ironman.

You then need to mark it as disabled like this:

```
$("#heroes-combo option[value='Ironman']").attr("disabled", true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code,

```
$('select').change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    $(this).children('option').each(function() {
        if ( $(this).val() === value ) {
             $(this).attr('disabled', true);   
        }
    });
});
```