# Disable dropdown option after selection once

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm working on a website where people can sign up for an event. We've got 8 different teams, based on superheroes. Every team should choose 1 of the 8 superheroes, but non of them should choose the same one.

Is it possible to write some code to disable an option (for every new visitor of the website) after someone has chosen that superhero?

So if 2 people has chosen a superhero, there will only be 6 choices left to choose. Those chosen options will be visible, but non-clickable.

So my html form code is (some titles/names are Dutch;)):

```
<form action="inschrijfformulier.php" method="post" id="cc-m-form-6876142651" target="_blank" class="cc-m-form cc-m-form-layout-1" onsubmit="javascript: setTimeout(function(){location.reload();}, 1000);return true;">
    <div class="cc-m-form-loading"></div>
        <div class="cc-m-form-view-sortable">
            <div class="cc-m-form-view-element cc-m-form-select" data-action="element" required>
            <label for="ma6b8be54cf86a6410">
                <div>Kies welke held jouw team is!</div>
                </label>
                <div class="cc-m-form-view-input-wrapper">
                    <select name="teamnaam" class="cc-m-form-element-input" required>
                        <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Selecteer</option>
                        <option value="Superman">Superman</option>
                        <option value="Batman">Batman</option>
                        <option value="X-Men">X-Men</option>
                        <option value="MegaMindy">Mega Mindy</option>
                        <option value="Spiderman">Spiderman</option>
                        <option value="TheHulk">The Hulk</option>
                        <option value="HitGirl">Hit Girl</option>
                        <option value="Meerminman">Meerminman</option></select></div></div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Naar betalen" data-action="formButton">
```

So if you make a selection and submit the form, it will link to inschrijfformulie.php, this .php file contains:

```
<?php 
$name = $_POST['teamnaam'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$rekeninghouder = $_POST['rekeninghouder'];
$aantalspelers = $_POST['aantalspelers'];
$spelernamen = $_POST['spelernamen'];
$formcontent="Teamnaam: $name \nEmail: $email \nRekeninghouder: $rekeninghouder \nAantal spelers: $aantalspelers \nSpelers: $spelernamen";
$recipient = "info@sidekickevents.nl";
$subject = "Inschrijfformulier";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
header("Location: https://www.ticketkantoor.nl/shop/bubbelvoetbal");
exit;
?>
```

This makes sure that I'm getting an email with the information they fill in. This works great, I also can see which superhero they've chosen.
Hopefully someone can explain it, because I'm new to PHP!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. SO is not a replacement for beginner’s tutorials.

Comment: Ok, but where should i ask it then..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable dropdown option after selecting (even for new visitors)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47648699/disable-dropdown-option-after-selecting-even-for-new-visitors)

Answer (score 0):

For the html to disable the OPTION

```
<select name="teamnaam">
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b" selected="selected">B</option>
    <option value="c" disabled="disabled">C</option>
    <option value="d">D</option>
</select>
```

For javascript to disable the OPTION

```
var dropDown = document.getElementsByName("teamnaam");
var dropDownOptions = dropDown[0].getElementsByTagName("OPTION");
for( var optIdx in dropDownOptions ){
    if(dropDownOptions[optIdx].value == 'd' ){
        dropDownOptions[optIdx].setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
    }
}
```

Remarks, It is handle the UI **only**, the logic for limit the qty of the hero select count should be handle by PHP.